# Callback a c++/cli method from a c# dll

Tags: callback, c++-cli

I have an application in which a winform is initialized by a c++/cli managed class. They both are seperate projects, generating dlls, and with Managed project referencing winform dll (obviously).

So now the scenario is on some button click in Winform I need to call a method in my managed class. I know delegates is the way to go but some small code snippet or some pointers on how I should go about doing this will be really helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of a C++/CLI function called from WPF.
On the C++/CLI side:

**cppcli.h:**

```
// cppcli.h

#pragma once

using namespace System;

namespace cppcli 
{
    public ref class cppClass
    {
        public:
            String^ cppFunction(int value);
    };
}
```

**cppcli.cpp:**

```
// This is the main DLL file.

#include "stdafx.h"  
#include "cppcli.h"

namespace cppcli 
{
    String^ cppClass::cppFunction(int value)
    {
        String^ message = gcnew String("The value you passed was: " + value);
        return message;
    }
}
```

Then on the C# side:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    cppClass cppObj = new cppClass();
    string message = cppObj.cppFunction(42);
    textBlock1.Text = message;
}
```

Result:
[image: The meaning of life]

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I edited the question above. I dont want to reference cli dll in C# project. So the soln proposed by you will still work?

Comment: So you want to call a C++ function from C#, but without referencing the C++ dll because it would cause a circular dependency? In that case you'll have to rethink the design of your application. You might be able to get around it if the C++ project is compiled as a DLL that you'll manually add to your C# project and use (I haven't tried it), but you should really re-think the design or have some more layers in between your projects.